# getting data from nested span tags

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to get weather data using this website    http://openweathermap.org/find?q= and the info i need lies in the following code:

```
<p>
 <span class="badge badge-info">6.2°С </span>
 " temperature from 5 to 7.8°С, wind 1.17m/s. clouds 0%, 1031 hpa"
</p>
```

I am using the following mechanism to do that:

```
import urllib
url = 'http://openweathermap.org/find?q=' + str(b)
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)

htmltext = htmlfile.read()

regex = '<span class="badge badge-info">(.+?)</span>'

pattern = re.compile(regex)   

temp = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

print temp
```

But the result i get is this:

```
["'+temp +'\xc2\xb0\xd0\xa1 "]
```

and it's the same for every keyword i search (the b seen above)

What am i doing wrong? Also how can i get the rest of the info included in the paragraph tag? Thanks in advance

Comment: Regular expressions are almost always the wrong tool for HTML.  Use BeautifulSoup or HTML5Lib.

Comment: @DietrichEpp does that mean i have to learn a new library? Is it included in the standard python libraries or do i have to download it?

Comment: Read this and then come back and read the answers below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/64004 ...
"the cancer that is killing StackOverflow it is too late it is too late we cannot be saved the trangession of a chi͡ld ensures regex will consume all living tissue "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use their JSON API instead of parsing the HTML? It would be much easier. You'll have all the data available to you, and you can reconstruct the paragraph using that data.

```
import json
import urllib

url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q=' + str(b)
request = urllib.urlopen(url)
text = request.read()

data = json.loads(text)

print u"{}\xb0C from {} to {}\xb0C, wind {}m/s, clouds {}%, {} hpa".format(
    data['main']['temp'], data['main']['temp_min'], data['main']['temp_max'],
    data['wind']['speed'], data['clouds']['all'], data['main']['pressure'])
```

You can read more about their API here: http://openweathermap.org/api

**EDIT**: Added °C in the string :)

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you can't get this temperature data from the site in question, it's not being included as static html. Your original regex worked, but it was finding the text `temp +'°С` or thereabouts, which is in a javascript function.

You could use Selenium, but it's much easier to get the data from the same place the Javascript function gets it from, the OpenWeatherMap API:

```
import urllib
import json

place = "Santa Monica"
apiurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0".format(urllib.quote(place))

jsonfile = urllib.urlopen(apiurl)
jsontext = jsonfile.read()
result = json.loads(jsontext)

temp_K = result['main']['temp']
temp = (temp_K - 273.15)*(9/5) + 32
print(temp)
```

Note that temperature comes back in Kelvin. This gives you:

```
49.51
```

It's chilly in Santa Monica today :)

[removed original answer based on BeautifulSoup, which would not work because the DOM element was generated by Javascript, so it doesn't exist in the static HTML]

Comment: I ended up with a blank list :/

Comment: the html is not exactly as given in the question, it appears the snippet in question is included in the page as raw text, and doesn't make it into the DOM. I'm looking at what else you can do, regex might actually be the easiest.